# setting asp image src property from javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set asp image element src property from javascript but the url property is not being set.

```
function slideshow() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/RollingScreen.aspx/GetNextImage",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{}",
    success: function (data) {
      //this changes the image on the web page
      $('#imgSlideShow').attr("src","~/1.png");
      $("#txt1").val(data.d);
      //fires another sleep/image cycle
      setTimeout(slideshow,5000);
    },
    error: function (result) {
      alert(result.message);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  //Kicks the slideshow
  slideshow();
});
```

My aspx image element is

```
<asp:Image ID="imgSlideShow" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="600px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/1.png"/>....
```

Can anyone please help me...

Comment: The image ID is not imgSlideShow when rendered.  View the source or inspect the element to see what the ID is, or use CssClass to give it a class name you can use to refer to it instead.  Also, you can't use ~ in javascript - only in .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you are trying to use ID which you have set in asp.net. But runat="server" elements are rendered with different IDs. Something like `Content1_Content2_imgSlideShow`. You can get it using `imgSlideShow.ClientID` on server side and than `$('#' + jsVariableWithClientID)`. But I prefer to use some unique class (no problem with passing client ID to JS):

`<asp:Image ID="imgSlideShow" CssClass="imgSlideShow" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="600px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/1.png"/>`

And than in JS, using class selector:

```
$('.imgSlideShow').attr("src","/1.png");
```

Another problem is that JS does not know about `~` - that is asp.net feature only. And you should specify image url for src like this:  `"/1.png"` (assuming it is located in root directory)

Comment: Thanks FAngel....The problem is solved....I used /1.png instead of ~/1.png...and it is working fine.....thanks a lot....u saved my time....